# XMLHttpRequest Open Access Denied

Tags: javascript, exception, xmlhttprequest, access-denied

I am trying to call open on xmlhttprequest in my javascript code but I am getting an exception "Access is Denied".

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doFunction() {
        alert("hi");
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        var url = "https://localhost:1234/test/pi/testing/operation";
        try{
            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        } catch(err) {
            alert(err.message);
        }
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
        var testText = document.getElementById("test").value;
        var jsonObject = { Status: "1", ErrorList: "", test: testText, Price: "" };
        var data = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
        xhr.send(data);
    }
</script>
```

The page itself is running on my IIS at localhost:8080 and I am trying to invoke my wcf service on localhost:1234.
I added https://localhost to my trusted sites but still not working why is that?

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added http://localhost to my trusted sites and started working.
The question and this answer applies for IE 10